# Build script arguments in Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, ear

so I have this build script that basically compiles and generates an EAR file. This script is executed within Eclipse using the "External Tools Configuration" wizard (play button with a suitcase icon). This script has values which seemed to be picked from a properties file or something similar to that. 
One such example is the base directory:

```
<echo message="${display.version}"/>
        <echo message="${basedir}"/>
```

I have searched the whole workspace but I can't find a single file that contains value for these items.
My question, how are these values being passed to this script?

Comment: Could you show more of the build script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say about `display.version` without seeing more of the build script, but `basedir` is frequently set as an attribute on the `<project>` element.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Comment: Matt, baseDir is defined as  basedir="../../" in project tag

Comment: Well, there's half your answer. `:)`

Comment: did you check out the environment variables? In eclipse environment variables or as startup parameters?